# XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:1426/api/Blogs/myarticle Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to access web api method but it is not being called and getting following error.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:1426/api/Blogs/Articles/GetArticlesForHome. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403

I have tried to access same api call from POST MAN and its working fine. To be interesting is that, I am able to access token authentication method from angularjs code but after enter the website not able to call any other method.

Following is the my angular js code.

```
this.GetAll = function () {
            var query = $http({
                url: appSetting.apiBaseUrl + "api/Blogs/Articles/GetArticlesForHome",
                method: "GET",
                data: {},
                headers: {
                    'SECRET_API_KEY': 'sdfdsfs',
                    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
                }
            });

            return query.then(function (response) {
                console.log("response.data", response.data);
                deffered.resolve(response.data);
                return deffered.promise;
            }, function (response) {
                console.log("response.error", response);
                deffered.reject(response);
                return deffered.promise;
            });
        };
```

I have already enable cors in web api. Please help me on this.

Comment: i dont understand a few things. [1] is why your browser does a preflight request for a GET method. [2] postman would not be a proof since its not CORS. ANYWAY 403 means that the server knows exactly what you want AND he knows why he doesnt want to give it to you so go look in the logs.